# How to reset angular form including custom validation errors.... None of recent answers helped ME

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following code....

```
this.authForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl("", [AuthValidator.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl("", [
        AuthValidator.required,
        AuthValidator.minLength(5)
      ])
    });
```

Now I want to reset this form, But When I call this.authForm.reset(), It throws error, can't read property trim of null....

I have the following Validators..

```
export class AuthValidator { 
    static required(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        return (c.value as string).trim() ? null : { required: true };
    }

    static minLength(len: number): ValidatorFn {
        return (c: AbstractControl) => (c.value as string).trim().length < len ? { minlength: { requiredLength: len, actualLength: c.value.length } } : null; 
    }
}
```

How can I reset my form ???????????????? PLEASE HELP

I tried all the tricks like..

this.authForm.markAsPristine etc.. But it failed....

Comment: any reason for using that custom validator ?

Comment: Yes try the form without you custom validators first. The exception is telling you that (c.value as string) is null

Comment: yes sir, Validators.required can be bypassed with spaces as long as I know sir

Comment: *built in angular validators.required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting the control value to a string in your custom validator. However, it can be `null` or `undefined` after the form reset. Modify your validator to check for a valid string before using `trim()`.

```
export class AuthValidator { 
    static required(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        return (c.value && (c.value as string).trim()) ? null : { required: true };
    }

    static minLength(len: number): ValidatorFn {
        return (c: AbstractControl) => (c.value && (c.value as string).trim().length < len) ? { minlength: { requiredLength: len, actualLength: c.value.length } } : null; 
    }
}
```